# Why does Describe function fail on annotation layer with RuntimeError: Object: Describe input value is not valid type?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, layers, mxd

I am accessing layers in an mxd programatically and also accessing the layer properties using the Describe function

```
 lyr =arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) # gets me the list of layers in mxd

 desc= arcpy.Describe(lyr[8]) #returns the properties of the layers
```

This last step fails at one of the layer "Annotation Class 1" as the layer has white space characters or a probable keyword ( I suppose) in it showing me the following error:

> RuntimeError: Object: Describe input value is not valid type

How do I handle that?

It is impossible for me to go and manually change all mxd layer names with whitespace, please help, thanks

Comment: For context, I think it would be helpful if you included more of the code you are using here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help anybody, but i stumbled upon this same issue.

I'm basically trying to add all layers that have a SHAPE column to a combobox in a Python Addin.  I was testing each layer in the data frame's isFeatureLayer property, but then discovered that annotation feature classes aren't considered feature layers.  So then I was going to use the describe technique and find all layers that had a SHAPE column, but then encountered that the "Default" "layer" that shows up with annotation fc's (the "Image" layer with orthos is similar) can't be described.

Therefore, i did this (and it works):

```
try:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
    fields = desc.fields
    for field in fields:
        if string.upper(field.name) == 'SHAPE':
            items.append(layer.name) # this is used later to populate the combobox
            break
except:
    pass
```